# Why windows service doesn't see environment variable?

Tags: c#, windows-services, environment-variables

In my windows service, I'm trying to read the value of environmental variable MY_SCRIPT. However, the service doesn't see it and

```
String myScriptPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_SCRIPT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

returns empty string.

Any explanation why?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you set up the env-var? It must be at machine level and not user level as services run under the context of another user.

Comment: I've set it up from user level. Now I've changed it to system and set it using my installer and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this variable set?

Environment is either inherited from parent process or changed in the process itself.